# How to control the whole board with 8 standard pieces?

Tags: chess

How to control the whole board with 8 standard pieces (one king, one queen, two rooks, two knights, two bishops)?

P.S. A piece doesn't control a cell simply by staying on it, so another piece must control it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a studied problem: [Oxford journal page](http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/32/6/567.full.pdf)

The three possible solutions are listed at the top of page 4.

[image: Three different chess diagrams where the 8 officers cover the whole board]

Also noteworthy: there is no option with the bishops on opposing colors.

Comment: I don't think you can claim copyright on a chess position. Here's a reproduction of the three positions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eAltb.png

Comment: You may have a point, I had no clue how to make what you just did, so I'd have to have taken a screenshot...

Comment: @r3mainer on chess position no, but specific image, probably, so can't simply screenshot the result here. But with chess, it's easy to just reproduce it on an online board editor (like [Lichess](https://lichess.org/editor)) and screenshot that.